# How to make movemail work on SSHFS filesystems?

Tags: debian, sshfs, lock, mailutils

I would like to avoid setting up an IMAP server and instead use mailutils' `movemail` in combination with `SSHFS` to move over some mails from an external host to my local machine. Unfortunately it fails:

```
$ sshfs -o noforget exthost:/ /mnt/sshfs
$ movemail /mnt/sshfs/var/mail/dirdi /home/user/dirdi/ext_mail
movemail: mailbox `/mnt/sshfs/var/mail/dirdi': cannot lock: Lock file check failed
```

However, the lock file `/var/mail/dirdi.lock` is actually being created on exthost. I had a look at the source code and tracked the error down until here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mailutils.git/tree/libmailutils/base/locker.c?h=release-3.5#n120 It seems to me that some check inside the `stat_check` function fails, but I can not tell which and why.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I created `smovemail`, a shell script which runs `movemail` on a local copy of the remote mailbox:

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize variables
status=0
src=
dest=
remotefs=
copy=
mountpoint=
lockfile=

# function to print errors
function error {
    echo "(E) ${1}" >&2
    status=1
}

# function to tear down created environment
function tear_down {

    # remove local copy of remote mailbox
    if [[ "${copy}" ]]; then
        rm -- "${copy}" ||
            error "Unable to remove local copy of remote mailbox '${copy}.'"
    fi

    # remove lockfile
    if [[ "${lockfile}" ]]; then
        rm -- "${lockfile}" ||
            error "Unable to remove lockfile '${lockfile}. Remote mailbox may still be locked.'"
    fi

    # unmount SSHFS
    mount | cut -d " " -f 3 | grep "${mountpoint}" >/dev/null &&
        fusermount -u "${mountpoint}" 2>/dev/null ||
            error "Unable to unmount remote filesystem mounted at '${mountpoint}'"

    # remove mountpoint
    if [[ "${mountpoint}" ]]; then
        rmdir "${mountpoint}" 2>/dev/null ||
            error "Unable to remove mountpoint '${mountpoint}'"
    fi

    exit ${status}
}

# register tear down function to run in any case
trap tear_down EXIT

# print usage
if [[ ${#} -ne 2 ]]; then
    error "Usage: $(basename ${0}) remote_mailbox local_mailbox"
    exit
fi
# TODO implement better parameter sanitization

# create mountpoint
mountpoint=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null) || {
    error "Unable to create mountpoint."
    exit
}

# determine locations
src="${mountpoint}/"$(basename "${1}" 2>/dev/null)
remotefs=$(dirname "${1}" 2>/dev/null)
dest="${2}"

# mount SSHFS
sshfs "${remotefs}" "${mountpoint}" -o workaround=rename,reconnect,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
    error "Unable to mount remote filesystem '${remotefs}'"
    exit
}

# lock remote mailbox
lockfile=$(mktemp -p "${mountpoint}" 2>/dev/null) || {
    error "Unable to create lockfile"
    exit
}
mv -n "${lockfile}" "${src}.lock"
if [[ -f "${lockfile}" ]]; then
    error "Unable to lock mailbox."
    exit
fi
lockfile="${src}.lock"

# create local copy
copy=$(mktemp 2>/dev/null) || {
    error "Unable to create copy of remote mailbox."
    exit
}
cp "${src}" "${copy}" 2>/dev/null || {
    error "Unable to copy remote mailbox."
    exit
}

# run movemail
movemail "${copy}" "${dest}" || {
    error "Unable to move mails."
    exit
}

# play back copy
cp "${copy}" "${src}" 2>/dev/null || {
    error "Unable to play back local copy."
    exit
}
```

It can be invoked by `$ smovemail remoteuser@remotehost:/var/mail/remoteuser /var/mail/localuser`

If you want to use this script, feel free to do so, but **please note**: This script leverages the `mv -n` command to lock the remote mailbox and therefore is based on the assumption that this command is **atomic** on SSHFS filesystems. Based on my research this assumption does not always hold! However, I ran some tests and was not able to crash it, so for me it is good enough.

Comments and suggestions for improvements are very welcome.